# How to remove '\' from my string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here I want to remove '\' from my jsong string.I tried with .replace('\', ''); but it is giving error.
Here is my string.

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify($scope.zoneArray).replace('\', '');
```

Output is like:`[\"sfaf\",\"lkkil\"]`

Comment: what is the error??

Comment: Could you please add sample string also?

Comment: try this `var myJsonString = JSON.stringify($scope.zoneArray).replace('\\', '');`

Comment: Try `'\\', ''`. You have a syntax error.

Comment: Let me try with this

Comment: Also, why do you want to remove it? You'll be left with invalid JSON.

Comment: where exactly do you see this output like `[\"sfaf\",\"lkkil\"]` - don't believe everything you see in the console (or learn to interpret it)

Comment: I will get more zones by seperating with comma. so i want to remove those / with my string

Comment: Trust the output of `JSON.stringify`

Comment: Why would the output of json stringify have a bunch of forward slashes. I suspect you are viewing this string in a c-compatible string parser. So it is displaying quotations marks with a forward slash infront of them (because thats how you write a quote mark inside a quote mark). I therefore suspect you have no issue, this would also explain why replacing \ does nothing (because isnt actually there)

Comment: @Sam ... \ is a backslash ... / is a forward slash - just sayin - also `replacing \ does nothing` - his code produces an error, because it's invalid syntax

Comment: right ok. so its a syntax error - bit confused why he has "output" then... and it has back slashes in it

Comment: the important thing is WHERE is that output. Console?

Comment: Only @JaromandaX seems to understand. Mike, your output does not have backslashes in it. You have double-quotes inside a quoted string, which are displayed with backslashes to make the representation a valid string literal. You have asked [an XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: by the way, `JSON.stringify` will never produce that output

Comment: Actually i am getting one array, I want to make that array formate to json formate

Comment: I suggest that you ask a new question, being sure to (a) explain clearly what you are trying to accomplish (b) what code you have written (c) what you expected it to do (d) what is occurring as a result. For (a), do not say "replace all backslashes", but the REAL goal.

Comment: `i am getting one array` - yes, good, you have an array, that's a javascript object, so good start. `I want to make that array formate to json formate` use *JSON.stringify* ... just JSON.stringify, don't mess with the string that is output by JSON.stringify unless you understand it's actual content

Comment: After convertion of my array into json. the output becomes like [\"sfaf\",\"lkkil\"], but i want `sfaf,lklk` like this

Answer (score 1):

To replace all characters, you need to set the global flag on the regex, which is the first parameter to replace. Like so:

```
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify($scope.zoneArray).replace(/\\/g, '');
```

Comment: This being said, I'm curious why you want to remove the backslashes. It will most likely make the JSON invalid.

Comment: removing backslashes that aren't there - this is the the only valid answer, but the question is flawed

Answer (score 1):

you need to parse json.

```
JSON.parse($scope.zoneArray)
```

Answer (score -2):

try use below format :

```html
var myJsonString = JSON.stringify($scope.zoneArray).replace('\\', '');
```

Comment: that will remove exactly one single \

Comment: wrong jaromanda - `' la \ la \la lall\\'.replace('\\', '')
-> " la  la la lall"`

Comment: wrong @Sam - there's only one `\\` in that string literal - right at the end - try this in your console: `var x = ' la \ la \la lall\\'; console.log('before:', x, 'after:', x.replace('\\', ''));`

Comment: I'm not getting u. Raju has '\\'. I was just responding to ur statement that will remove only 1 \ but Raju's code would appear to remove all \ in the string.

Comment: it doesn't remove **what isn't even there**

Comment: `Raju has '\\'.` - yes, that's a string literal for a SINGLE BACKSLASH - javascript 101

Comment: to retype my badly formatted comment - there's only one \ in that string literal - right at the end - try this in your console: `var x = ' la \ la \la lall\\'; console.log('before:', x, 'after:', x.replace('\\', ''));`

Comment: right, i know that. i thought u meant it would remove only one slash from the source string - which you are correct it appears to do only that which was a surprise to me. `'sds s\\ sd \\ s\\'.replace('\\', '')` => `sds s sd \ s\` I would have expected that output so be 'sds s sd s'. I f'd up my test by including single \ in my source string. My apologies! Full retraction/am currently eating my shoe :)

Comment: There are two issues. You only had one backslash character in your source string, AND your answer only replaces the first instance of a backslash character in any string. (And there is the issue that the OP's string doesn't have backslashes at all.)

Comment: @Phrogz - the fact that no \ exist in the actual string makes it easy to assume that one has the right answer. but `.replace('random string', '');` will also "work" :p